# Problem selecting Global navigation item for application pages

Tags: application-pages

I have created one navigation menu in sharepoint 2013. The menu contains some application pages and some site pages. When i select the link from the menu , the selected item color block color changes. it works fine for sitepages but if the page is application page, the color doesnt get applied to it. when i do F12, i see that .static is selected for sitepages but not for application pages.

Any idea? please help